# Servlets: where are web.xml files searched for? How are multiple web.xml files merged?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I know from the Servlet 3 spec that `web.xml` is looked for in the `WEB-INF/` directory. However, I believe there are other `web.xml` files. For instance, [Tomcat has a `web.xml` file under `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html). I think one can also put a `web.xml` file under `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/`.

Am I correct that there can be multiple `web.xml` files? If so, what locations can they be in, and in what order order are they processed, and what are the semantics for "merging" them?
(The Servlet spec speaks of merging `web-fragment.xml` files, but I assume that's a separate thing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different side to your question.

## Tomcat's own web.xml

The servlet specification allows the container (Tomcat here) to define some defaults components (JSP, default servlet...).
As you saw, Tomcat provides a default web.xml to do it (and one only, in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`).
That web.xml allows Tomcat to configure [among other things](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/conf/web.xml) :

1. A default servlet (which serves the files directly)
2. A jsp servlet to compile and execute jsp (and jspx) files
3. Differents mime mapping

Tomcat's web.xml is always parsed before the one in an application. So any application can override the values defined by tomcat.

So to answer your question: in Tomcat, there is one web.xml which applies to all webapps (in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf` directory) and the webapp's own web.xml.

## web-fragment.xml

Since the [version 3.0 of the servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), the web.xml can be a combination of the WEB-INF/web.xml and a number of `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` that the container can find in the webapp classpath (`WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib`).

The order in which those web-fragment are parsed can be determined.

And Tomcat can log the resulting web.xml with the logEffectiveWebXml attribute on the context ([see doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html))